# Moving dpkg to foreground during confirmation screen glitch

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, apt, dpkg

I was doing a routine `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` on my server. The dpkg program displayed a dialog box about a package that had updated its default ini file. I wanted the new file, but wanted to move changes from my old ini file to the new one, so I used `ctrl + z` to move the dialog to the background and made copies of my old file. When I brought the dialog back to the foreground the arrow keys stopped working (they output escape sequences when pressed).

What is the cause of this problem, and is it safe for me to kill the upgrade process and start again from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + z` stopps the process. Try bash command **fg** to bring back the dialog to foreground when copy was done. This should continue execution of the stopped process.